# ASP.NET Web API best practice to send data to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, api-design

I am currently developing the ASP.NET Web API application and I am sending data to the server using the `route parameters` and I also able to send the data in the `body` like the in the `JSON` format and send it to server.

**Example:**

```
http://localhost:59035/api/Authors/AddAuthors/MyTokenKey/AuthorName
```

And If I send the data in the body like this:

```
TokenKey=MyTokenKey&AuthorName=AuthorName
```

Than my server method is also called. In both way we can send the data.

So confusion is which is best way to send the data to server?

1. In routing parameters
2. In the body.

If we pass the data into `route parameters` than it is visible to the others, it does not matter the our request is in which method, like `POST`, `GET` or anything else..

Good practice to call the Web API.

I also want to know which is good method to called the web API, from the `server side` or from the `client side`.

For example I created the Web API and hosted on the `one domain` and I want to call that `Web API` from `another domain`. So which is better way to call the API from the `client browser using AJAX` or call I have to call the `Web API` from the Server.

1. Web API must be have to call from the `Server` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference in passing parameters with `GET` or `POST` request is that `GET` has limited parameter length, and we can consider `POST` parameters to be unlimited. So it depends on you which method to choose.

What about calling API using AJAX or using another WebAPI. AJAX does not support cross-domain requests without additional operations. If you have your API deployed on `domain1` and you want to call it using AJAX request from `domain2`, then on `domain1` you should define a cross-origin header which allows requests from `domain2`.

If it is your API, you can define such a header. If it is a third party API, which does not allow cross-origin requests, you might need to call it from your own WebAPI.

Comment: Thanks, But in which method we have to call the API? like from the `Clients browser using the AJAX` or at the `server` ?

Comment: It is my `own API` but I want to made available to my all the `domains` and in the `Android` and `IOs` aslo. It is safe to allow the  "cross-origin request" ?

Comment: If it is an open API, you may allow access from any domain by settings cross-origin header to `"*"`

Comment: So where I have to set this header? at the client side where I have to call the API or at the Web API project?

Comment: You should set it on your API side
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api